# Generate all unique combinations of Items

Tags: java, algorithm, unique, combinations

I trying to generate all possible unique combination of items.

```
Ex: item1, item2, item3

Combinations: 
   item1+item2+item3
   item1+item2
   item1+item3
   item2+item3
   item1
   item2
   item3
```

I am unable to get an idea on how to solve this?

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
   for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++){
       System.out.println(list.item(i)+list.item(j));
   }
}
```

The above code certainly works for all unique combination of two elements. But not for 3 element pair and more..

Comment: How about combinations with one item only?

Comment: pls take a look at my answer and say if it helped.

Comment: @assylias, that's also valid combination. you can pick single item too. I forgot to mention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have N items, count from 1 to 2^N-1. Each number represents a combination, like so: if bit 0 (the least significant bit) is set, item1 is in the combination. If bit 1 is set, item2 is in the combination, and so on.

If you don't want 1-item combinations, start counting at 3, and ignore all the combinations that are a power of 2 (4, 8, 16, etc...).

Comment: sorry I didn't understand. any pseudo code? Running time of your algorithm.

Comment: The running time is O(2^N) where N is the number of items. You can't beat that, as there are O(2^N) combinations.

Comment: is it going to be so complex? Could you please write down the code to print as requested. Struggling :P

Comment: It's not complex at all. Anyway, try it yourself, and if you're struggling with the code ask another question.

Answer (score 4):

guava has that build in, *if that's an option*

```
 Set<Set<String>> result = Sets.powerSet(Sets.newHashSet("item1", "item2", "item3"));
    for(Set<String> token : result){
        System.out.println(token);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following Java solution uses the bit approach proposed by **zmbq** :

```
  public static void allComb(int n) {
    BitSet bs = new BitSet();
    while (bs.length() <= n) {
      System.out.println(bs);
      //Inc by 1
      int pos = bs.nextClearBit(0);
      bs.flip(0, pos + 1);      
    }
  }
```