# Multiply elements with other elements in a list

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and I'm writing a program in Java.

How do I multiply every element in a list with every other element i the list?
Like this:
[1, 3, 5, 7] should be multiplied like this:
1 * 3 + 1 * 5 + 1 * 7 + 3 * 5 + 3 * 7 + 5 * 7

How do I write an algorithm for this? I know it is something in this way but my mind can't figure out what I have to add / change.

```
    for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
        sum += (list.get(index) * (list.get());
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425346/generate-all-unique-combinations-of-items

Answer (score 1):

As @WJS posted, a nested loop is a simple, but slow solution - it's time complexity is `O(n^2)`. You could use a single loop to achieve same result, but with `O(n)` complexity: notice, how you can express the sum as `1 * (3 + 5 + 7) + 3 * (5 + 7) + 5 * 7`: the left multiplier is current index position, and the sum in the left multiplier is previous suffix sum.

```
long prevSuffixSum = 0, result = 0;
for (int i = nums.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    long val = nums.get(i);
    result += val * prevSuffixSum;
    prevSuffixSum += val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These approaches are provided based on your implied requirement that you must explicitly multiply each pair of elements and take their sum.  There are other ways to achieve the sum that are more effiicent.

You need a nested loop.

- the outer loop starts at `i = 0`.
- the inner loop starts a `k = i+1 = 1`.
- this ensures the sum doesn't include the square of each entry.

```
List<Integer> nums = List.of(1,3,5,7);
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
    for (int k = i+1; k < nums.size(); k++) {
        sum += nums.get(i)*nums.get(k);
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Prints

```
86
```

You could also do it like this using an enhanced for loop as the outer loop.  But the first method is, imo, more straight forward.

```
int sum = 0;
int i = 1; 
for (int v : nums) {
    for (int k = i++; k < nums.size(); k++) {
        sum += v*nums.get(k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> ints = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(-1,3,5,7));

        Integer total = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < ints.size() ; i++){
            int counter = 1;
            while (counter < ints.size() - i){
                total += ints.get(i) * ints.get(i+counter);
                counter ++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```